# Transponse result of SELECT (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query :

```
SELECT ParentID, Type, Value FROM table1
```

and result :

```
| 1 | First  | Val1  |
| 1 | Second | Val2  |
| 2 | Second | Val3  |
| 3 | First  | Val4  |
| 2 | First  | Val5  |
| 3 | Second | Val6  |
```

So, how to modify this query to get result :

```
| ParentID | First | Second |
-----------------------------
| 1        | Val1  | Val2   |
| 2        | Val5  | Val3   |
| 3        | Val4  | Val6   |
```

Comment: Will you have more than 2 values for `type`?

Comment: Check for [**PIVOT**](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Use Pivot function to solve this problem

Comment: @Lamak yes, type have about 8 values.

Comment: @Kushan Can you show example for my case ?